# Can a barcode scan populate 2 fields?

Tags: barcode

I am trying to update a textview with a barcode scan. The issue is that my software will run in the background. The admin will scan a bar code which will populate a textbox on his desktop application. I want to get the same information on my software (running in the background). 
1. An easy way is that the Admin copies the number (after scanning the barcode) from his application and pastes it to my application.
2. Another way is that my application gets updated automatically/simultaneously when the Admin scans the barcode for his application.

Option 1 is not what we are looking for. However, we are confused if option 2 is a valid option. Kindly comment. 
I am building my application on JAVA. OS: Windows 98 (the one used by Admin).  The barcode is being populated by another system. All these systems are on the same server.

Comment: You'll need to provide a lot more information before anyone can help. For example, what operating system are you running on? What language are you developing your software in? What software is your Admin using, and how is the barcode being populated? etc. The more specific you can be, the more likely someone can help. As it stands, the only real answer is "possibly".

Comment: Okay. Updated a bit. Do I need to add some more information? To read the barcode data from the barcode and populate my software with it will require me to understand the algo used by the system that creates the barcode. is it true?

Comment: It's still very hard to know without more specifics - there are potentially lots of options such as intercepting the input from the barcode reader (if there is one) or communicating with whatever application your Admin is using. You should add everything you possibly can to the question, and add relevant tags such as java and windows to bring it to the attention of more people. Having said that, Windows 98 is pretty old at this stage, and you may have difficulty getting answers.